# How to find Gain when i have frequency of input and output signal

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, frequency-response

I need to find the bandwidth of an filter, for this im generating frequency of  1Hz to 200 hz in step of 1hz from a function generator Im expecting -3db point anywhere between 1 and 200

The output of the device is voltage signal, here i take FFT and find the output frequency

so can i calculate gain in DB by just dividing output frequency/Input frequency?

My aim is to find the -3db point

Answer (score 0):

No need for an FFT. Just divide the output voltage by the input voltage. The frequency where this is closest to $\sqrt{2}$ is your corner frequency (for a lowpass or highpass). For a bandpass you should end with two frequencies, one below and one above the maximum of the bandpass.

Or better: try one of the many methods to measure a transfer function in one go. (sweeps, pseudo random noise, etc.)